Searching the Sandbox is somewhat broken
When I try to search the Sandbox for proposals with a specific word in them, using a query like inquestion:2140 interleave, I get this error message:

Oops! We can't understand your search terms:inquestion:2140 interleave

Searching inquestion:2140 or inquestion:2140 user:me, however, works as expected.
I haven't been able to reproduce this error on any other question, either on meta or the main site.

I can reproduce all of these as stated, plus inquestion:2140 -test works but not inquestion:2140 test.

We have been unable to get some dev time to take a look at this so it is being marked as status deferred till we have some time that it can be addressed.
